# Heroku Database issues

Tags: discord.js

So I am making a discord bot, and I am hosting it with heroku. I also have databases, (just simple json files) that are being updated constantly when someone adds my bot in their server. It is fine and all, up until where i want to update something. Because when I want to update something, the file I have on my pc is behind the one on heroku has. I am wondering if there is a way I can download the files from heroku, or use a different service for my database? I don't really know what to do for this.

Comment: JSON files are **not** databases. Heroku dynos have [ephemeral filesystems](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem), so you'll lose state every time the platform needs or decides to restart your app. Move state out of your dyno per e.g. https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted.

Comment: Well I realize that. But you did not answer my question. I am also wondering if I should change the database I am using, and how

Comment: As @jonrsharpe pointed out, JSON files are **not** databases. Luckily, Heroku provides [a free Postgres database](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql).

Comment: @jonrsharpe How would I use the postgres? I have no idea at all

Comment: Then search e.g. *"Postgres JavaScript tutorial"*

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your problem is that you want to be up-to-date on whenever your bot is added to a server. Not really familiar with Heroku but I'll just toss out some ideas.

1. You can setup a webhook or dedicated channel in your discord server so that your bot on heroku will post updates there.
2. Every time someone adds the bot, the bot will grab the json file from Cloud Firestore, make edits, and save it back to Cloud Firestore. Then you'll be able to access your file from cloud easily anywhere.
3. Save the json file in Heroku's postgres database as a blob (or table of records). Add webserver code to bot and tell heroku to start it as a web dyno instead. Serve that json file on a route. Then you'll be able to download the file with just your browser anywhere.